# Android - are there precompiled samples from SDK available anywhere?

Tags: android, sdk, sample, precompiled

Are there precompiled samples from SDK available anywhere? Or is there any way to quickly compile all samples from given SDK version?

**UPDATE**: it looks like everyone needs to compile examples by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the sample applications in Eclipse then deploy them on your Android device or the emulator.

If Eclipse, ADT and required tools are installed, it should be quite fast.

Comment: Or, if you're not an Eclipse guy, just run `android update project -p .` from within the samples directory, then run `ant install` to compile and install them. The first command will generate the necessary build files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for already complete projects that you just need to deploy take a look at the Notepad tutorial download. It contains the completed solutions, ready to go.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

The sample apps are also complete, working apps.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html